# Can't call a sub class function, in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

What I was doing before was that I was calling a function of my interface and it determinate in a switch condition thanks to a parameter what to do with the data. What kind of specialization they have.

But now, what I am trying to create a local object, treat it, and then add it to my containers of the interface.
In order to do that I have to copy all the value of my local object (which have been treated) in my container of the interface.
So I created a copy_cell function in the interface, a virtual one, and one in the subclass. But whenever I try to do it the interface function is called and not the subfunction.

```
           GridCell_voxel * local_cell;


           local_cell = new GridCell_voxel(m_grid_map( cell2matindex_x(cell_index_x), cell2matindex_y(cell_index_y))->getVoxelResolution(), m_grid_map( cell2matindex_x(cell_index_x), cell2matindex_y(cell_index_y))->getVoxel().size());

           local_cell->process_points(relevant_points, m_mapping_type);

//This is the line I need to change
           local_cell->copy_cell (m_grid_map( cell2matindex_x( cell_index_x), cell2matindex_y( cell_index_y))) ;
```

Do you have any idea on the way to go? What am I missing here?

Comment: There isn't enough information in the post to identify the source of the problem. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Put an `override` specifier behind the declaration of a function `copy_cell` in a class `GridCell_voxel`. You will see, that you don't override it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @zdenek, it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the lack of information, i will try to expose how i managed  and what i was actually looking for.

So i have a container of IntefaceCell, called m_grid_map, full of cell that has been specialized. In my case m_grid_map is full of GridCell_voxel which is a sub class from InterfaceCell.
What i want to do is, create a new local GridCell_voxel, copy the information in it. Then process the informations, then copy the local cell in the container.
The important part is the dynamic_cast in the copy cell function, which allow you to take an InterfaceCell as argument and then treat it as GridCell_voxel.

```
//Main.cpp 
                        GridCell_voxel * local_cell;
                        local_cell = new GridCell_voxel();
                        local_cell->copy_cell (m_grid_map( cell2matindex_x( cell_index_x), cell2matindex_y( cell_index_y)));
                        local_cell->process_points(relevant_points, m_mapping_type);
                        m_grid_map( cell2matindex_x( cell_index_x), cell2matindex_y( cell_index_y))->copy_cell (local_cell);
                        delete local_cell;

//GridCell_voxel.cpp
    void GridCell_voxel::copy_cell(GridCellInterface* cell) {

        GridCell_voxel* voxel_cell = dynamic_cast<GridCell_voxel*>(cell);

        this->m_voxel_start_height = voxel_cell->m_voxel_start_height;
        this->init = true;
        this->m_ground_voxel_position = voxel_cell->m_ground_voxel_position;

    }
```

I hope it will help someone.